# c++ getting error for object creation expected ;

Tags: c++

In the following program i am getting error like this
Addtime.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Addtime.cpp:41:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘time1’
I checked thoroughly the program, not able to find the error. please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class time
{
    public:
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;

    void showtime()
    {
       cout<<"time is "<<hours <<"hours:"<<minutes<<"minutes:"<<seconds<<"seconds \n";
    }

    time(int temph,int tempm,int temps)
    {
        hours=temph;
        minutes=tempm;
        seconds=temps;
    }
    time operator +(time t2)
    {
        int temph; 
        int tempm; 
        int temps;

        temph = hours + t2.hours;
        tempm = minutes + t2.seconds;
        temps = seconds + t2.minutes;

        tempm = (tempm + temps)/60;
        temps = temps % 60;
        temph = (temph + tempm)/60;

        tempm = tempm % 60;

        return time(temph,tempm,temps);
    }
};

int main()
{
    time time1 (12,15,15);
    cout<<"the first value is";
    time1.showtime();
    time time2(10,30,30);
    cout<<"the second value is";
    time2.showtime();

    time time3;
    time3 = time1 + time2;
    cout<<"the result is";
    time3.showtime();

    time time4;
    time4 = time1 + time2 + time3;
    time4.showtime();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take the twenty seconds necessary to indent your code so we can actually read it... That's not the first time either.

Comment: Ramraj plz. y u no insert indent?!

Comment: you are missing a default constructor?

Comment: It's possible that `time.h` will be implicitly included, which will cause a thousand extra errors to pop up from a conflict between your class `time`, and `time_t time(time_t *);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to your snippet in an online compiler after I've fiddled with it a bit:

http://goo.gl/7WReTM

It looks like `time` clashes with the `time` function from the C standard library.

As such, the way to fix this is to either rename your class to something else (in the link I called it `timer`), or to declare each instance with `class time` to disambiguate the symbol.

Note that your variables `time3` and `time4` try to use the default constructor, which doesn't exist since you added a 3-argument constructor which suppresses the default, so neither of those will compile (I've commented them out in my example).

Comment: Thanks brother, your answer worked correctly. but I am not able to understand this statement made by you "Note that your variables time3 and time4 try to use the default constructor, which doesn't exist since you added a 3-argument constructor which suppresses the default, so neither of those will compile (I've commented them out in my example).". Please explain me in detail.

Comment: @RamrajSanthanam read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor

Comment: Briefly, if you don't add any constructors of your own, the compiler will create a default, no-argument constructor for you. Your variables `time3` and `time4` are both created without arguments passed to their constructors, so they're trying to use the default. But because you've added a constructor, that default doesn't exist. You'll need to add a default constructor manually if you want that kind of thing to work. Try uncommenting the appropriate lines in the linked code and you'll see the kind of error you'll get.

Comment: Thanks brother for your valuable response. yes it works with default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it failed to compile at these lines that want to call the default constructor:

```
time time3;
....
time time4;
```

The reason is that if you write any other constructor manually (in your case: `time(int,int,int)`), the compiler will no longer generate the default constructor for you.

To solve it, you will need to further add a default constructor for your `time` class.

Comment: It fails on another line

Comment: @Slava is right, this is an error but it's not *the* error that's being asked about. Adding a default constructor still won't make the example compile.

Answer (score 0):

add a default constructor time(void){/*code*/};
You need one if you declare an object like this time time4;